# Отделение прямой речи от последующего текста

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу понять, как отделяется последующий текст от окончания прямой речи, записанной через тире, как в данном случае:

— *Стой!* — поднялся часовой. — *Тебя не знаю*. Я тяжело вздохнул.

Вижу только два варианта:

1) не использовать запись через тире:

"*Стой!* — поднялся часовой. — *Тебя не знаю*". Я тяжело вздохнул.

2) начинать новый абзац:

— *Стой!* — поднялся часовой. — *Тебя не знаю*.

Я тяжело вздохнул.

Оба варианта мне не очень нравятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что здесь нужно использовать оформление в абзац.

В  одном абзаце с прямой речью **можно продолжить авторский текст**, но он должен  находиться **после слов автора**, а не после прямой речи, например:

— Стой! Тебя не знаю! — поднялся часовой и  решительно загородил мне дорогу. Я тяжело вздохнул, спорить было бесполезно.

А дальше можно продолжить диалог или авторский текст следующего абзаца.

Такое оформление используется в художественных произведениях, а в правилах информации не эту тему не много.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138